# A command-line tool to navigate through the output of previous commands?

Tags: shell, terminal

Is there a tool for that?

If there is none what level should this tool be available at?

- the shell should track the output

or

- the terminal emulator

Comment: Common terminal emulators provide a scrollback buffer. Is it not enough for you? If not, why not? What is your specific usage case? requirements?

Comment: If you're using bash, try the `history` command. or CTRL+R

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski scrolling through the previous output is not easy, especially when the output is big enough.

Comment: Alacritty has [vi mode](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/docs/features.md#vi-mode) which can be entered through using Ctrl+Shift+Space that allows you to navigate through the output of your terminal using vi bindings. Kitty has the [scrollback buffer](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/overview/#the-scrollback-buffer).

Comment: @ZaidhaanHussain it is pretty fast, I wonder how I never heard of it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is output of a single command you may just pipe it to `less` and navigate exactly as you do for man pages:

```
command | less
```

The output will be lost after quitting less with `q`. To not lose it, you may use `command | tee command.output | less`, in which case it will feed the output into less, but also write it into the file `command.output`.

If you want to record the whole session, consider running everything within `screen` or `tmux` session. Both of them have logging and look-back capabilities; look for the respective manual pages for details (both have a huge single-page manuals). For instance, this is how you log the whole session (as it appears interactivly) with the screen:

```
screen -L command
```

The file `screenlog.0` will be created, which you can explore with `less`.

This is how you can navigate within the `tmux` session (without recording it to disk):

```
tmux new command
```

Inside `tmux` window press `Ctrl+B` then immediately `PgUp` and now you can scroll the window with PgUp, PgDown, arrows, also you can select parts of the screen to put it somewhere afterwards. The command will be running and, possibly, producing new output, which will be immediately shown once you exit scrolling mode by pressing `Esc`.

Comment: Though that is not exactly what I was asking for, but it helps thanks